# Angular4: Due to dragstart event is firing due to mousedown event

Tags: angular

I have a div which have the mousedown event of the parent and on that div only i have added the dragstart event, But when i try to drag it does not fires drag start event,

I tried by doing event.stoppropagation() event in the mousedown event on div, Then this mousedown evvent get fired but dragstart event is not firing..

Is there any way i can give priority to drag start event instead of the mousedown event.

Comment: can you add your code

Answer (score 0):

Add global variable `isDragging` and set it to true on dragstart. In mousedown event do:

```
if( isDragging ) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: when we remove the mousedown event from the event listerer tab in developer tool then only the dragstart event gets called,